# Email.date formatting

Tags: ruby, email, date, format

When using `email.date.to_s`

I receive a date in this format

`Wed, 3 Jun 2015 14:57:46 -0700`

but I want it to be in this format

`06/03/15`

Comment: Welcome to SO, and to ruby!  Is `email.date` an instance of `Date`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) to format the string:

```
Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
#=> 09/16/15
```

Comment: But that is for `time.now` . How would it be used with `email.date.to_s`. It doesn't seem to work when I just add `strftime("%m/%d/%y")`

Comment: As @Jared Beck asked, what kind of object is `email.date`?